# error occur when i run awk command write in .sh file and run in cygwin terminal

Tags: shell, sed, awk, cygwin

i have cygwin terminal for run shell script(.sh ) file...it work good..but when i add awk command in shell script and then run Error occur

```
/usr/bin/gawk.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygsigsegv-2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestion for run awk in cygwin terminal??

Comment: It would help to see the code you are using.

Comment: Looks like your cygwin installation is incomplete or corrupted.

Comment: Does gawk work from the command line, outside of the script?

Answer (score 0):

Please try updating your installation.  `gawk` has not used `libsigsegv` in some time.